# Multiple list of strings together

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have the following two lists:

```
Sites = ["iTunes","Google"]
PurchaseTypes = ["Rental","Purchase"]
```

How would I multiply all combinations together, thus yielding:

```
[
    "iTunesRental",
    "iTunesPurchase",
    "GoogleRental",
    "GooglePurchase"
]
```

Is there a python operation to do this? Or is it required to do a `for` loop for each list? That is:

```
combined = []
for s in sites:
    for pt in purchase_types:
        combined.append(s+pt)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
>>> [a + b for a in Sites for b in PurchaseTypes]
['iTunesRental', 'iTunesPurchase', 'GoogleRental', 'GooglePurchase']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) -

```
>>> Sites = [
...         "iTunes",
...         "Google"
...     ]
>>>
>>>
>>> PurchaseTypes = [
...         "Rental",
...         "Purchase"
...     ]
>>>
>>> from itertools import product
>>> l = ['{}{}'.format(*i) for i in product(Sites,PurchaseTypes)]
>>> l
['iTunesRental', 'iTunesPurchase', 'GoogleRental', 'GooglePurchase']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for map-reduce lambda operations. Map-reduce operations are slower than list-comprehensions. But again this is one of the styles of Pythonic programming.

In your case, it can be done as follows:

```
combined = reduce(lambda a,b:a+b,map(lambda x:map(lambda y:x+y,Sites),PurchaseTypes))
```